# Kotlin: Access a public field from a Java class that also overrides a public getter of the same name

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a Java class (which I cannot edit, because it's auto-generated by Thrift) defined like this:

```
public class TheirException extends Throwable {
  public String message;

  public TheirException(String message) {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public String getMessage() {
    return this.message;
  }
}
```

However, if I try to get `message` from Kotlin, `getMessage()` is not available and produces an `Unresolved reference` error. Trying to use the `message`field produces the following error:

> Error:(470, 30) Kotlin: Overload resolution ambiguity:
>   public final var message: String! defined in com.example.TheirException
>   public open val message: String? defined in com.example.TheirException

However, if I instead do:

```
(exception as Throwable).message
```

it resolves fine.

Why is casting to `Throwable` necessary here, why is `getMessage()` not available, and what is causing the ambiguity?

Comment: Can you try getFoo()? kotlin allows accessing by the same method name as well.

Comment: What kotlin verison are you using? In 1.3 `javaClass.foo` directs to the field and `javaClass.getFoo()` to the method

Comment: Why at all do you have a public field with a public getter? Make the field private!

Comment: @Deepak `getFoo()` is not available "Unresolved reference".
@Lino version 1.3.20
@Seelenvirtuose The question is about how to use the generated class from Kotlin, not about how to change the original class.

Comment: In kotlin 1.3 I was able to compile and execute code with `.foo` as well as `.getFoo()`

Comment: I was also able to compile and execute both .foo and .getFoo()

Comment: OK, thanks. I simplified the example from the actual code. I'll make a simple test too to check that it works, then try to find out if there's a problem with this specific class.

Comment: I discovered the problem is caused by inheriting from `Throwable`. I've solved the problem, but now the question is *why*? :-) I've updated the question.

Comment: Because, in Kotlin `message:String!` and `message:String?` are different types

Answer (score 2):

The ambiguity is caused by the fact that `message` is public. Kotlin translates every getter to a property **even if there are no backing fields**. If you add another function to this class:

```
public String getSecondMessage() {
  return "second message"; // Note that this getter does not rely on a field
}
```

You can access it like this in Kotlin:

```
TheirException("message").secondMessage
```

If `message` is public and there is a `getMessage()` function Kotlin creates 2 getters and on the call site you newer know which to use. In your example the 2 getters would have the same behavior but that is not always the case.

When you cast your class to a `Throwable` you explicitly tell the compiler that this class has the signature of a `Throwable`, which means you define that there should be only one `message` getter, this resolves the ambiguity. Note here that Kotlin has its own definition of a `Throwable` (this will be important later).

Now you might ask why there is no `getMessage()` function. This is because you are casting to `Throwable` and not `java.lang.Throwable`. The Kotlin definition of `Throwable` has no `getMessage()`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. While this explains the ambigiouity is there a kotlin way of accessing the raw method? One thing i can think of is creating an explicit java accessor that is unambiguous

Comment: Creating an explicit java accessor would solve the problem, another solution would be to use reflection to explicitly call the method.

Comment: If I create a class and add a public field and a getter, they are both accessible from Kotlin. It's only adding inheritance that causes the problem, so I don't think your explanation is correct.